# Extra "appendix" when referencing using cleveref in elsarticle

Tags: cross-referencing, appendices, cleveref, elsarticle

How do I get rid of the extra "appendix" appearing when I cross-reference an appendix section? Example output is "...see appendix Appendix A". MWE as follows:

```
\documentclass[preprint,3p]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{Title}

\author{Author}
\ead{email@uni.edu}

\address{Address Here}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract abstract abstract
\end{abstract}

\end{frontmatter}

\section{Section1}
We would like to reference \cref{sec:app}. And the same for \cref{sec:app2}.

\appendix
\section{Section One} \label{sec:app}
Something here

\section{Section Two} \label{sec:app2}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to suppress the cross-reference name for a particular type, it's simpler to just use

```
\crefname{appendix}{}{}
```

Then all the formats get defined for you automatically, instead of having to redefine `\crefformat`, `\crefmultiformat`, `\crefrangeformat`, and `\labelcrefformat` separately. (These days, `cleveref` is clever enough to omit the usual non-breaking space after the cross-reference name if you define an empty name.)

*However*, this solution (and ach's too) will break `cleveref`'s multi-reference features somewhat. E.g. `\cref{apdx1,apdx2,apdx3,apdx5,apdx7}` will produce "Appendix 1 to Appendix 3 and Appendix 4 and Appendix 5", instead of "Appendices 1 to 3, 4 and 5".

Luckily, `elsarticle` defines an `\appendixname` macro to hold the string used in appendix labels, no doubt to allow it to be customised easily. So the best solution is simply to get rid of `elsarticle`'s `\appendixname` entirely, and let `cleveref` do its job as usual, by adding this to your preamble:

```
\def\appendixname{}
```

Comment: Note that it should be `\crefname{appendix}{}{}` not `\crefname{appendux}{}{}`

Answer (score 2):

The `elsarticle` class evidently redefines the labels for the appendices to contain the word "Appendix", but `cleveref` assumes alphanumeric labels that need a word with them.

A simple solution to this clash is to redefine the way `cleveref` formats the appendix references, via `\crrefformat{<type>}{<format>}` (cf. section 7.2.1 of the `cleverref` manual).

Applied to your MWE it would be

```
\documentclass[preprint,3p]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\crefformat{appendix}{#2#1#3}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{Title}

\author{Author}
\ead{email@uni.edu}

\address{Address Here}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract abstract abstract
\end{abstract}

\end{frontmatter}

\section{Section1}
We would like to reference \cref{sec:app}. And the same for \cref{sec:app2}.

\appendix
\section{Section One} \label{sec:app}
Something here

\section{Section Two} \label{sec:app2}

\end{document}
```

This yields

> We would like to reference Appendix A. And the same for Appendix B.